# How to check whether SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege has been enabled?

Tags: privileges, windows-server-2012-r2

On Windows Server 2012R2, how to check *SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege* is enabled or not? 
In another word, how to enable *SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege*, or other specific priviledges?

Answer (score 0):

If Cygwin is installed, `editrights` can be used, for example:

```
/usr/bin/editrights -u vagrant -a SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege
```

This is not a direct answer to native approach, but it may be a starting point.